My replica database forest status shows "sync replica" for long time
My replica database forest status shows "sync replica" for a long time but other forest bulk sync-up is completed and changed to open replica, but only one forest is showing sync replica in the forest status page also I didn't see any error. If anuone faced this issue have solution for this.

Do you see any activity in the logs for that forest? Turn on Debug level if you haven't already (it's not that much volume for ErrorLog.txt but can be helpful to see what's going on)
